# Opening Nautilus hangs with CIFS shares mounted

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba, freeze, cifs

Ubuntu 20.04 desktop here, fresh install. Have set up 3 cifs mounts from a NAS in /etc/fstab (mounted as smbv3). It's all working great except every time I open a new nautilus file dialog/explorer. The process of opening nautilus freezes for 15-20 seconds before the window finally is shown (It does not output any debug info in the terminal).

I can access the mounts from everywhere else without any hiccups - it seems to only be a nautilus issue. Any idea how this could be fixed? It's a bit tiresome to wait a long time every time a file dialog opens.

Comment: I run a NAS and I do not think you have a problem. I see the same thing if the hard drives in the NAS are resting and you make a request it takes a few seconds for them to spin up. You define 15 seconds as a long time sheesh.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the NAS resting. The drives are spinning 24/7 :)

Comment: That would be a very strange NAS but if you say so.

Comment: It might be a question of protocol: it is possible that your PC look for the server name using a protocol not supported by your NAS, then try another protocol, and so on until the right one is found.  You could evaluate if your NAS and PC are configured for WINS.  Another hint is to check whether Windows Discovery (WS-discovery) is activated on your NAS.

Comment: What is on the NAS? Hundreds of files or hundreds of files that produce thumbnails? Look at the setting for nautilus ( Preferences > Search and Preview. If you have "All Files" selected for Thumbnails and File Count that may slow things down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @David. I have a Synology 920+ that is the same way at times. Although, as you say in this instance that the rest of the system responds adequately, I think the issue here is Nautilus itself.

Each program decides how it will access a piece of data. If `nautilus` uses a different system call, or a call from a different library, then the side effects will likely be different as well. Perhaps the method getting called under the hood is not responding well with `rsync`, or it could be a different reaction altogether.

Regardless, the result is the same. I do not see it being something that you can control without switching your file mgmt. gui.

One way to find out without any loss is to download another similar app, and run it alongside `nautilus`. Switch back and forth for a week or so, and any difference should be apparent.

Another option, if you know the destination path beforehand, is to navigate via terminal to the directory that you need and open from there. This can be done with a single command:

```
cd <PATH> && nautilus
```

where  is to be replaced with the actual path. If the destination is a file, the command is:

```
cd "<PARENT-PATH>" && nautilus "./<FILENAME>"
```

with the same replacement for . Using double quotes will provide a layer of safety from things such as spaces in file pathnames, but will still let bash expand symbols like `./`, `~`, and `*`.